# Super+w Unity shortcut is slow

Tags: 14.04, unity, nvidia, shortcut-keys

I am trying to figure out why super+w is unresponsive. When I press the shortcut, it takes about 1-2 seconds before the animation starts. The animations are very smooth entering and exiting the 'expose' mode. All the other dash shortcuts (ctrl+alt+U/D/L/R, ctrl+super+d etc) are very responsive and trigger as soon as I press the combo.

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and have a nNvidia NVS 310 video card. I'm using proprietary drivers (version 340.93 from nvidia-340-updates)

How can I figure out why the command is slow to start?

Comment: Updating so someone else might find this useful:

I'm running the Slack and Spotify desktop clients which are both based on Chromium in addition to Chrome. Turning off hardware acceleration in Slack and Spotify seems to speed things up a bit. The system is much more responsive when chrome is not